# How to disable page validation when clicking previous in a wizardstep

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I try to click the previous button in a wizard step on my page, it wont return to the previous page until all of the fields are valid. I have turned of CausesValidation. Is there an issue with this in a wizard? My code follows:

```
<StepNavigationTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="StepPreviousButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="MovePrevious"
            Text="Previous" OnClientClick="DisableButton(this);" UseSubmitBehavior="False"
            CssClass="bigButton" />
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811040/wizard-control-in-asp-net-how-to-set-the-nextbutton-causesvalidation-property-t) asked on SO. This explains how you can disable the validation in steps. You basically will have to take care of it in the code.

Comment: Didn't work. CausesValidation is set to false but it seems like it just ignores it!

Comment: It seems setting in the markup didn't work for that person and had to be done in code. did you try that?

Comment: Yes that's what I did. No luck.

Comment: is there something else on the page thats causing the validation?

Answer (score 0):

For all your validator controls in the asp page set them to enabled=false. Then in your code behind for the next button click or whatever button you want the validators to work, set the validators to enabled=true.

asp.net:

< asp:RequiredFieldValidator Enabled="False" ID="TitleRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TitleTextBox" ErrorMessage="Title is Required." ToolTip="title is required" ForeColor="Red">*< /asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

vb:

```
Protected Sub CreationWizard_NextButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.WizardNavigationEventArgs) Handles CreationWizard.NextButtonClick
    If (CreationWizard.ActiveStepIndex = CreationWizard.WizardSteps.IndexOf(Me.WizardStep1)) Then
        TitleRequiredFieldValidator.Enabled = True

    End If
```